# How to use an USB 3G modem data connection with an Android phone (Galaxy Nexus)?

Tags: usb, samsung-galaxy-nexus, 3g, usb-on-the-go

I own a Galaxy Nexus phone and i'd like to know if there is a way i can use an USB dongle to provide it with an Internet connection.

I imagine I will need some kind of adapter (and some Google searches suggested an USB OTG cable).

I'd like to know if the stock OS supports this (i have Android 4.2.2 currently) and if I'd need root or a customer kernel. Also, if it is possible, could you please provide a guide on how to do this?

Comment: OTG cable is correct. And yes, that should work. To be sure, you might try it in a shop. Setup sometimes depends on the dongle -- but as soon as that and the SIM it it is recognized, the corresponding menus should get visible in the device settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Officially**: This is not possible, except for certain (older?) Archos tablets.

**Inofficially**: There's the [Autopatcher project](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1719408) . It includes patches to enable 3G modems on wifi-only tablets (it may be possible to use those on phones too, but YMMV).

Autopatcher supports these Android firmware flavours:

- some 3rd party firmwares (CyanogenMod, AOKP, ParanoidAndroid, PACman)
- AOSP 2.3- > 4.3 (e.g., Google's Nexus line)
- ...and others

Not supported are original HTC, Samsung and other branded firmwares.